# Is there any disadvantage of using: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Tags: http, utf-8, http-headers, ascii, content-type

My web server serves content that is in 95% of the time just simple ascii. However in some rare cases, the content contains some German non-ascii characters.

Now I could set the `content-type` response header by detecting if the content contains any non-ascii characters, or I could just always set the response header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Is there any disadvantage in doing the latter?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Nope, all it's there for is to tell the browser which character set to decode your response with.

Answer (score 16):

No, there is no disadvantage -- but you'll need to spell `"utf-8"` correctly.

Comment: UTF-8 isn't wrong.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1
section 3.1.1.1 (Media Type) includes:
> the following examples are all equivalent, but the first is preferred for consistency:
text/html;charset=utf-8, text/html;charset=UTF-8, Text/HTML;Charset="utf-8", text/html; charset="utf-8"

section 3.1.1.2 (Charset) states: "A charset is identified by a case-insensitive token."

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17934505/revisions

Comment: I see- the OP originally used "UTF8", which is incorrect.  That definitely adds context as to why you needed to correct the spelling.  I hope my note at least adds some value about what now appears to be a comment about just case differences.

Answer (score 12):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so it is perfectly safe to declare the `charset` as `utf-8` for an all-ASCII document.